# Fixing "crc32 tool not found" on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, crc32

I'm trying to build [spark/firmware](https://github.com/spark/firmware) on Ubuntu, but when running `make` I only get the following error message

```
../build/common-tools.mk:26: *** "crc32 tool is not found".  Stop.
```

I tried using

```
apt-get install crc32
```

but there is no such package. How can I install the `crc32` tool?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use

```
sudo apt-get install libarchive-zip-perl
```

I found the correct package by using `apt-file`:

```
sudo apt-file update && sudo apt-file search /usr/bin/crc32
```